# ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up. when running Spark in CRON

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a spark-submit in a bash file scheduled with cron. If I run the bash file manually, the spark app works perfectly. However, running it with cron gives the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply add the path of my bash profile at the top of my bash file.